# Why is my array returning empty? And how do I ensure it copies the data into my third selection

Tags: excel, vba

After countless efforts to keep the array "newvarray" within range, I am now running into a result of an empty array from a 278 line column. I believe this is also the root cause of my endgame function not executing (pasting unmatched values into the rolls sheet)?

Clarification: the actualy empty cells report on locals as "Empty", the columns with string report as " "" "

```
Dim oldsht As Worksheet
Dim newsht As Worksheet
Dim rollsht As Worksheet

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer

Set oldsht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Insert Yesterday's Report Here")
Set newsht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Insert Today's Report Here")
Set rollsht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rolls")

Dim OldVArray(), NewVArray(), RollArray() As String

ReDim Preserve OldVArray(1 To oldsht.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 5 To 5)
ReDim Preserve NewVArray(2 To newsht.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 5 To 5)
ReDim Preserve RollArray(1 To rollsht.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 3 To 3)

For a = 2 To oldsht.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    OldVArray(a, 5) = oldsht.Cells(a, 5)
Next a

For b = 2 To newsht.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NewVArray(b, 5) = newsht.Cells(b, 5)
Next b

For c = 2 To rollsht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    RollArray(c, 3) = rollsht.Cells(c, 3)
Next c

Dim Voyage As String
For a = 2 To UBound(OldVArray)
    Voyage = OldVArray(a, 5)
    
    For b = 2 To UBound(NewVArray)
    voyage2 = NewVArray(b, 5)
        If voyage2 <> Voyage Then
            If voyage2 <> "" Then
                For Each cell In NewVArray
                voyage2 = rollsheet.Range("C:C")               
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Here are snips of sample idea, highlighted are the rows that need to be found, and the voyage that changed is in orange. Third on Rolls would be the output of the macro.

Oldsheet:
[image]

Newsheet:
[image]

Rolls:
[image]

Comment: `= newsht.Cells(b, 5)` is column E. I think you want A?

Comment: I have A for my redims to capture everything, not all of the same row column E cells are populated yet that is the data I need

Comment: That inner `For c = 2 To UBound(RollArray)` just repeatedly replaces the value of `NewVArray(b, 5)` with `RollArray(c, 3)` until it hits the last iteration.  Is that intended?  Maybe you can expalin exactly what the code is intended to do?  It's not really clear from your posted code what that is.

Comment: Try some basic debugging steps - assign your Range Rows to a variable and `debug.print` results. Also when you string your DIMs on one line - only the last one is the type you defined. The first two are `Variants` As in `Dim oldsht, newsht, rollsht As Worksheet`

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry as I am new to this, I am attempting to pull the data from oldsheet and newsheet, find anything in newsheet that does not match the old, and post these new updates into the rollsheet, only the cells that have changed. and without empty cells.

Comment: Does each row in "old" and "new" have an identifier which should match a row in the other sheet?  "update" is only new idenetifiers, or any row which has a change?  A small sample dataset would be useful here, with the rows(s) which would be copied to "Rolls" highlighted.

Comment: @TimWilliams As I said I'm still learning, so I appreciate you helping. Attached now are snips of sample data, or would you rather I make tables in the post? I also moved the code around to no avail but changed the Dim lines.

Comment: Is there a column in both sheets which uniquely identifies a record? Cont ? # ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but this is how I'd do it.  Just going from your screenshots. If your actual data looks different then you will need to make some adjustments.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook, oldsht As Worksheet, newsht As Worksheet, rollsht As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, id, col, cDest As Range, copied As Boolean, m
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set oldsht = wb.Sheets("Insert Yesterday's Report Here")
    Set newsht = wb.Sheets("Insert Today's Report Here")
    Set rollsht = wb.Sheets("Rolls")
    'next empty row on Rolls sheet
    Set cDest = rollsht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    'loop colA on new sheet
    For Each c In newsht.Range("A2:A" & newsht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Cells
        id = c.Value         'identifier from Col A
        If Len(id) > 0 Then
            m = Application.Match(id, oldsht.Columns("A"), 0) 'check for exact match on old sheet
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                'got a match: check for updates in cols B to C
                copied = False
                For col = 2 To 3
                    If c.EntireRow.Cells(col).Value <> oldsht.Cells(m, col).Value Then
                        If Not copied Then 'already copied this row?
                            cDest.Resize(1, 3).Value = c.Resize(1, 3).Value 'copy changed row
                            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1) ' next empy row
                            copied = True
                        End If
                        cDest.EntireRow.Cells(col).Interior.Color = vbRed 'flag updated value
                    End If
                Next col
            Else
                cDest.Resize(1, 3).Value = c.Resize(1, 3).Value 'copy new row
                Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1) ' next empy row
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: It's tricky because the new sheet has additions, new info for the new day, and more rows being added. The column I want to see if it is changing is actually "E", but we need only check that for items that are in "A" on both sheets - so yes that identifies the record. Your code returned a lot of non-problems. I hope I am explaining what I am trying to do well enough. If I just change "col = 5 to 5", this should solve?

Comment: Yes just change to `For col = 5 To 5` (the logic in that loop could be simplified in that case also, but will be fine as-is).  You'll also need to change those `Resize(1, 3)` to `Resize(1, 5)`   If there are new id's which aren't matched to the "old" data then those rows are also copied over.

Comment: It turns out this dataset didn't have mismatches, funny enough. Thank you SO much for the help.